# Toggle menu is not getting collapse when the screen size is mobile size

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have tried the basic bootstrap to get a toggle menu. But it does not get expand when the screen size is m. It is getting collapsed.But when the toggle icon is clicked it does not get expanded

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">NinjaXeries</a>
            <button 
            class="navbar-toggler" 
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#ccs"
            >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ccs">

                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Price</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">General</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Galle</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>            
        </div>

    </div>
    
    





   <div class="container mt-3">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 ">
            <h1 class="text-center">Our Destination</h1>
            <p class="text-center lead">Let's Go</p>
        </div>      
    </div> <!--row-->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-2 col-xxl-2">
            <h1 class="text-center">Berlin</h1>
            <img src="img/img1.jpg" width="250px" height="250px" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid">
            <P class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur non, mollitia voluptates nemo culpa perferendis numquam, et totam, minus labore libero accusantium recusandae magnam incidunt.</P>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-2 col-xxl-2">
            <h1 class="text-center">Sri Lanka</h1>
            <img src="img/img2.jpg" width="250px" height="250px" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid">
            <P class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur non, mollitia voluptates nemo culpa perferendis numquam, et totam, minus labore libero accusantium recusandae magnam incidunt.</P>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-2 col-xxl-2">
            <h1 class="text-center">Canada</h1>
            <img src="img/img3.jpg" width="250px" height="250px" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid">
            <P class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur non, mollitia voluptates nemo culpa perferendis numquam, et totam, minus labore libero accusantium recusandae magnam incidunt.</P>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-2 col-xxl-2">
            <h1 class="text-center">Europe</h1>
            <img src="img/img4.jpg" width="250px" height="250px" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid">
            <P class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur non, mollitia voluptates nemo culpa perferendis numquam, et totam, minus labore libero accusantium recusandae magnam incidunt.</P>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-2 col-xxl-2">
            <h1 class="text-center">Nether</h1>
            <img src="img/img5.jpg" width="250px" height="250px" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid">
            <P class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur non, mollitia voluptates nemo culpa perferendis numquam, et totam, minus labore libero accusantium recusandae magnam incidunt.</P>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-2 col-xxl-2">
            <h1 class="text-center">Amster</h1>
            <img src="img/img6.jpg" width="250px" height="250px" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid">
            <P class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur non, mollitia voluptates nemo culpa perferendis numquam, et totam, minus labore libero accusantium recusandae magnam incidunt.</P>
        </div>
    </div>

   </div>
    


   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are including bootstrap too many times. you only need one of version 4 or 5

Answer (score 1):

**Issue is this line:** data-bs-target="#ccs"

Please replace it with this: **data-target="#ccs"**

Comment: it worked. But after expansion it won't get collapse for the touch